# Right number of rows, but they're empty

Tags: django, django-tables2

I'm trying to display some tables, but they come up empty. The part that gets me is the number of rows is correct, but they are completely blank. If the table has 9 entries, I get 9 empty rows.

The same code is working for a different table

**tables.py:**

```
class VouchersTable(tables.Table):
    class meta:
        model = Vouchers
        fields = ('event_name', 'pk', 'valid_start', 'valid_end', 'lab_duration', 'user_email', 'redeem_date' )
```

**views.py:**

```
class ReportsView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'reports.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ReportsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        vouchers = VouchersTable(Vouchers.objects.all())
        RequestConfig(self.request, paginate=False).configure(vouchers)
        context['vouchers'] = vouchers

        return context
```

**reports.html:**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}

{% block content %}
  {% render_table vouchers %}
{% endblock content %}
```

**models.py:**

```
class Vouchers(models.Model):
    creator_uid = models.IntegerField()
    user_id = models.IntegerField()
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    user_email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    event_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    event_code = models.IntegerField()
    valid_start = models.IntegerField()
    valid_end = models.IntegerField()
    redeemed = models.IntegerField()
    redeem_date = models.IntegerField()
    lab_version = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    lab_model = models.IntegerField()
    lab_id = models.IntegerField()
    lab_duration = models.IntegerField()
```

**resulting html (empty lines removed):**

```
<div class="table-container">
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> 
        <tr class="even">
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: You probably need to post your ``Vouchers`` mode also.

Comment: the model has been added

Comment: Just to be sure: do you have a custom django_tables2/table.html template somewhere? It seems to miss some spaces for the default `table.html` implementation

Comment: No custom table.html. As mentioned above, the empty lines have been removed to shorten the post. The exact same code works for a different model (the only difference being the names and list of fields)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh well... 
You've declared the table like this:

```
class VouchersTable(tables.Table):
    class meta:
        model = Vouchers
        fields = ('event_name', 'pk', 'valid_start', 'valid_end', 'lab_duration', 'user_email', 'redeem_date' )
```

The correct way to write it is `class Meta` (**M**eta with a capital M): https://github.com/jieter/django-tables2